# Flutter leading image height width not working

Tags: flutter

I am adding an image as icon in appbar at leading position. But its width height not working i try to wrap it in a container and give width and height but don't know why its not reducing

```
leading:  Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      xOffset = 280;
                      yOffset = 150;
                      scaleFactor = 0.6;
                      isDrawerOpen = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: Width * 0.01,
                    child: Image.asset('images/ic.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
leading:  InkWell(              
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  xOffset = 280;
                  yOffset = 150;
                  scaleFactor = 0.6;
                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                });
              },
              child:  Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('images/ic.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 18,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
            )
```

OR

```
leading:  InkWell(              
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  xOffset = 280;
                  yOffset = 150;
                  scaleFactor = 0.6;
                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30.0,
                child: Image.asset('images/ic.png'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
            ),
```

One of them will work..

Comment: Made some changes. If this doesn't work I need more info on what you are trying to achieve?